Issue trying to use GetDIBits to capture a portion of the screen/window
Context:
I'm trying to make a bit of code that can essensially detect the framerate of a target window. My current goal is to use a checksum to check if the window has changed. The specific situtation I'm wanting to use this for the contents of the window move in a scrolling fasion so a low stride count for the checksum is fine.
Background:
When I first started writing this code I quickly noticed that the GetPixel (gdi32) function was very slow so it took 2000+ ms for checking just 100 pixels.
After a couple of google searches I came across the method of using a native bitmap to read a portion of the device context which was apparently way faster than GetPixel even for reading singular pixels.
Issue:
As far as I can tell, the GetDIBits (gdi32) function isn't writing anything to my output array. Using breakpoints I noticed that the buffer and output array were being left all 0 and using a basic for loop to randomize the contents of the arrays confirmed that the values were not being written as 0, they were just not being written.
The main part of the code in question is this:
public RGBQuad[] GetBitmap(int x, int y, uint width, uint height)
{
    var newDC = CreateCompatibleDC(context);
    var map = CreateCompatibleBitmap(context, width, height);
    SelectObject(newDC,map);
    var info = new BitmapInfo();
    info.header.bitCount = 32;
    info.header.compression = 0; // BI_RGB
    info.header.planes = 1;
    info.header.width = width;
    info.header.height = height;
    info.header.size = biSize;
    var pixels = new RGBQuad[width * height];
    BitBlt(newDC, 0, 0, width, height, context, x, y, 13369376 /*SRCCOPY*/);
    GetDIBits(newDC, map, 0, height, pixels, ref info, 0 /*DIB_RGB_COLORS*/);
    DeleteObject(map);
    DeleteDC(newDC);
    return pixels;
}

Note: I've tried using this code with both the window device context and the screen device context.
These are my declarations for the extern methods:
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr context, uint width, uint height);
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr context);
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr context);
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr context, IntPtr obj);
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr obj);
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr dstContext, int dstX, int dstY, uint width, uint height, IntPtr srcContext, int srcX, int srcY, uint operation);
[DllImport("gdi32")]
public static extern int GetDIBits(IntPtr context, IntPtr bitmap, uint start, uint lines, RGBQuad[] bits, ref BitmapInfo header, uint usage);

Feel free to ask for any clarification.

Any particular reason you don't just use Graphics.CopyFromScreen? That's a whole lot easier than futzing around with device contexts and all that happy stuff. Yes, it's fast.

That does seem to be a good option (though it does use the device context stuff in the backend). One question: is there an equivalent function for targeting a specific device context as I would prefer to target the window rather than the screen?

You could conceivably get the DC from the window handle, but why? Get the window handle and query the window rect. That should give you the screen coordinates of the window, which you can then use in a call to Graphics.CopyFromScreen.

While not nessasary, I figured fetching from just the window might be faster (even if only a little), plus more reliable in that another program partially covering a portion of the window wouldn't interfere with it

Are you sure the declaration of GetDIBits is passing the RGBQuad array as a pointer and not by value? I don't remember what the default marshaling is for arrays.

arrays are marshaled to pointers for the function. for example, the windows forms declaration for it is public static extern int GetDIBits(HandleRef hdc, HandleRef hbm, int uStartScan, int cScanLines, byte[] lpvBits, ref NativeMethods.BITMAPINFO_FLAT bmi, int uUsage); however the system.drawing declaration is public static extern int GetDIBits(HandleRef hdc, HandleRef hbm, int arg1, int arg2, IntPtr arg3, ref NativeMethods.BITMAPINFO_FLAT bmi, int arg5);
